# Stop a minecraft server from an other cmd windows

Tags: java, python, minecraft

i want to stop a Minecraft server (java) from an empty cmd window (in the server window, we just can type "stop" to stop the server),
because I want to automatize the start and the stop of the server with os library with :

```
os.system("the command i search")
```

I don't want to kill the task , because with this method, the server is not stopped properly, and we lost a lot of data.

Comment: You will have to keep hold of the process' input stream and write into it. Exact details depend on how you do your starts, but canonically one would use `Popen` for that.

Answer (score 1):

As for automation of the start of the server, that's simple. Either put a shortcut to your server file in your Startup folder in Windows or put a shortcut to your `run.bat` file in the same folder. For shutting it down, that might be a pain. I can tell from using the `os.system()` method that you're using Python. Stopping the server from a clear command window is something I don't know how to do, but I did find a "life-hack" you can do. [This plugin](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/serverrestart-1-13-1-16.57570/) is made to automatically restart your server at a specific time of day. But you should be able to configure it to *just* shut down, instead of a restart. Even if you made it restart, you could make the PC it's hosted on shut down just after the server restarts. This would cause a crash, granted, but it would also save all progress.